# removing lines include values higher than the determined threshold

Tags: text-processing

I have a data file such as:

data:

```
arht    -0.1006 0.0001  0.0147  100     arht    0.0012  -0.0002 0.0182  100
arht    -0.0006 1.0006  0.0133  100     arht    0.1011  0.0003  0.0175  100
bcmn     0.0005 0.0011  0.0165  100     bcmn    0.0015  0.0007  0.0197  100
ffgf    -0.0009 0.0012  0.0121  100     ffgf    0.0007  0.0010  0.0150  100
ffgf    -0.0004 0.0009  0.0105  100     ffgf    0.1008  0.0006  0.0151  100
```

I use the following command to extract the lines include the values higher than the absolute 0.10 for 2-3-4 and 7-8-9 columns:

```
awk 'sqrt($2*$2)<=.1 || sqrt($3*$3)>=.1 || sqrt($4*$4)>=.1 || sqrt($7*$7)>=.1 || sqrt($8*$8)>=.1 || sqrt($9*$9)>=.1 {print}' data > output
```

I need to remove these lines from the data file. How I can modify the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a duplicate question [Extracting the values greater than a threshold in text file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367006/extracting-the-values-greater-than-a-threshold-in-text-file#comment2347709_1367006)
If so, you need to correct the first term of your code:

```
awk 'sqrt($2*$2)>=.1 || sqrt($3*$3)>=.1 || sqrt($4*$4)>=.1 || sqrt($7*$7)>=.1 || sqrt($8*$8)>=.1 || sqrt($9*$9)>=.1) {print}' data >output
```

Then all you have to do is to add a negate sign (!) in front to get what you want:

```
awk '!(sqrt($2*$2)>=.1 || sqrt($3*$3)>=.1 || sqrt($4*$4)>=.1 || sqrt($7*$7)>=.1 || sqrt($8*$8)>=.1 || sqrt($9*$9)>=.1) {print}' data > output
```